# Question about linear (in)dependency

Tags: linear-algebra

I have a question about linear dependency.

Suppose we have a set $S$ of functions defined on $\mathbb{R}$.

$S = \{e^x, x^2\}$. It seems very intuitive that this set is linear independent. But, we did something in class I'm unsure about.

Proof:

Let $\alpha, \beta \in \mathbb{R}$.
Suppose $\alpha e^x + \beta x^2 = 0$
We need to show that $\alpha = \beta = 0$ is the only option to make sure that this linear combination equals 0.

(Here comes the part I'm unsure about)

Let $x = 0$, then $\alpha e^0 + \beta 0^2 = 0$
$\Rightarrow \alpha  = 0$

But if $\alpha  = 0$ then follows that $\beta = 0$.
So $S$ is linear independent.

My actual question:

Why can we conclude that the set is linear independent, just by saying that $x = 0$ makes it work? Shouldn't we show that it works for all $x \in \mathbb{R}$?
Can someone give a **detailed explanation**, as I didn't quite understand the teacher's explanation.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Actually you use *two* points; when you have that $\alpha=0$, use $x=1$ to get that $\beta1^2=0$, so also $\beta=0$. This is just noting that $x^2$ is not the zero vector. Once you have proved $\alpha=\beta=0$ for two points,  what more do you need?

Comment: Cause your first equality must be satisfied by All $x \in \ \mathbb R$ and in particular for $x=0$.

Comment: Exactly, I only show that it holds for 1 point! It has to hold for all points in the domain! Could someone elaborate?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The two functions are linearly dependent if exists $(\alpha, \beta)$ **constants** , different from $(0,0)$, such that $\alpha e^x + \beta x^2=0$ for **all the $x$**  in the considered domain.

So if for **some specific values of $x$** the condition above does not subsists, it does not hold for **all $x$**, so the functions are independent.

Your teacher attempted and find such a point at $x=0$, for which $(0,\beta)$ results. This solution however does not hold for ,e.g., $x=1$. For those two points no $(\alpha,\beta) \ne (0,0)$ can be found, so the two functions are linearly independent.

Answer (score 0):

We have $$\forall x \in \mathbb{R}, \alpha e^x + \beta x^2 = 0$$

Your goal is to determine all the possible values of $\alpha$ and $\beta$. Clearly, $\alpha=\beta=0$ is a solution, but can there be other solutions?

What are the properties that $\alpha$ and $\beta$ must satisfy?

In particular, we can derive some conditions by fixing certain values of $x$.

By setting $x=0$, we conclude that $\alpha$ must be $0$. We can recover $\beta$ by letting $x=1$.

Clearly, we can get more conditions by fixing more values of $x$, but just from these two conditions, we have concluded that the unique solution is $\alpha=\beta=0$.

Comment: Why is it unique?

Comment: $\alpha$ and $\beta$ must satisfies $\alpha=0$ and $\alpha e + \beta = 0$, We can solve the system and see that it is unique, that is both of them are zeroes.